# where to add the tcp.xml file for clustering in Liferay Community 7.4?

Tags: tomcat, liferay

I have edited the tcp.xml file of the com.liferay.portal.cluster.multiple-5.0.15.jar of the Liferay CE Foundation - Liferay CE Portal - Impl.lpkg. But I don't know where to add it from the server. Could you help me?

I add this in portal-ext.properties:

```
cluster.link.channel.properties.control=[CONFIG_FILE_PATH]/tcp.xml
cluster.link.channel.properties.transport.0=[CONFIG_FILE_PATH]/tcp.xml
```

But what is this PATH "CONFIG_FILE_PATH"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cluster.link.channel.properties.control=/jgroups/tmb-tcp.xml
cluster.link.channel.properties.transport.0=/jgroups/tmb-tcp.xml

save in: tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\jgroups